# Yes, sir, no siir, three bags full sir

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

Is there a Latin expression which is used by someone who sarcastically or semi-humorously pretends to be completely subservient and complies with everything that is asked of him (without even questioning it)? Apparently in Spanish an equivalent phrase is used ‘sí señor, no señor, lo que mande/diga el señor’.
English examples in context are in context are:-
-Get forensic on to it right away.' 'Yes, sir,' Hatchley said through clenched teeth as he left. Banks could almost hear the 'three bags full, sir'.
-Our new manager doesn't want to hear our opinions, all he wants is, 'Yes sir, no sir, three bags full si
Obviously, the ‘three bags full, sir’ is from the nursery rhyme’ and this phrase is sometimes used on its own.